# Module identification

Tags: identification, module

Can anyone recognize this module in this pic here? I am analysing a circuit and it would help me a lot!

[image: unknown_module]

Comment: It looks like a bunch of photodiodes like something Hamamatsu might offer.

Comment: It would help to know the length, the type of circuit it came from, and anything else about it. Was it poking out through a whole in the case of whatever it was in, for example?

Comment: it's CCD element in a refractometer. Sorry I am just a beginner

Comment: and it's 9mmx3mm

Comment: just found it here thanks

Comment: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/photodetector-arrays/7857692/

Comment: Wait a minute, you'd identified the part with this link and it contains the datasheet. What else do you know need to know? If you don't need anymore help, please close the question **or** you can answer your own question and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It the [TLC1401C](https://ams.com/documents/20143/36005/TSL1401CL_DS000136_3-00.pdf/8de4cae4-354c-c2c3-8db4-6a132f969a0a) Linear Sensor Array from AMS.
It has 128 tiny photodiodes. We use it for reading codes in 
 absolute positioning systems.
Further reading: [position encoders with simple graycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Position_encoders)